# Formality and symplectic forms on a smooth manifold

Tags: cv.complex-variables, sg.symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I saw one paper which asks this question.

"Let $(M,\omega,J)$ be a Kähler manifold. Then does $M$ admit a symplectic structure $\sigma$ of non-hard Lefschetz type?".

I was wondering whether I could ask the similar question but instead of "hard Lefschetz property" I will replace with "formality".
That is:

> Let $(M,\omega, J)$ be a Kähler manifold. Is there a symplectic structure $\sigma$ on $M$ which is of non-formal type?

Comment: Note the first question was answered by Yunhyung Cho https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.1418.pdf.